# Compare Series containing None

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the python shift function to compare if a value in a Series is equal to the previus value. Basically

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series([2, 2, 4, 5])

a == a.shift()
Out[1]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

This is as expected. (The first comparison is False because we are comparing with the `NA` of the shifted series). Now, I do have Series where I don't have any value, ie. `None`, like this

```
b = pd.Series([None, None, 4, 5])
```

Here the comparison of the two `None`s gives `False`

```
b == b.shift()
Out[3]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

I'd be willing to accept some sort of philosophical reasoning arguing that comparing `None` is meaningless etc., however

```
c = None
d = None
c == d
Out[4]: True
```

What is going on here?!

And, what I really want to know is; how can I perform my comparison of my `b`-Series, given that I want it to treat `None`'s as equal? That is I want `b == b.shift()` to give the same result as `a == a.shift()` gave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `None` get casted to `NaN` and `NaN` has the property that it is not equal to itself:

```
[54]:
b = pd.Series([None, None, 4, 5])
b

Out[54]: 
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    4.0
3    5.0
dtype: float64
```

As you can see here:

```
In[55]:
b==b

Out[55]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

I'm not sure how you can get this to work correctly, although this works:

```
In[68]:
( (b == b.shift())  | ( (b != b.shift()) &  (b != b) ) )

Out[68]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

You'll get a false result for the first row because when you `shift` down you're comparing against a non-existent row:

```
In[69]:
b.shift()

Out[69]: 
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    4.0
dtype: float64
```

So the `NaN` is comparing `True` from the boolean logic as the first row is `NaN` and so is the shifted series' first row.

To work around the first row False-positive you could slice the resultant result to ignore the first row:

```
In[70]:
( (b == b.shift())  | ( (b != b.shift()) &  (b != b) ) )[1:]

Out[70]: 
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

As to why it gets casted, `Pandas` tries to coerce the data to a compatible numpy, here float is selected because of the `int`s and `None` values, `None` and `NaN` cannot be represented by `int`s

To get the same result as `a` in your example, you should overwrite the first row to `False` as it should always fail:

```
In[78]:
result = pd.Series( ( (b == b.shift())  | ( (b != b.shift()) &  (b != b) ) ) )
result.iloc[0] = False
result

Out[78]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: For parties interested to know how this works, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864912/how-are-inf-and-nan-implemented

Comment: Another good SO about NaN and boolean logic.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925797/why-python-pandas-does-not-use-3-valued-logic/43925913#43925913

Comment: Aha! :) Thanks. Any thoughts on the last part of the question? I really dont want to introduce a dummy like 999 or similar

Comment: You may want to slice the series so you ignore the first row perhaps, I'll update

Comment: I'll give it a go a little later (currently commuting :)) and mark your reply as the answer if it works!

Comment: It'd make sense to set the first row to `False` as it should always fail in the comparison, I'll show how to do this

Answer (score 1):

If it is okay for you to compare neighboring entries in a periodic manner (ie., the last entry is compared to the first one) there is another, simple solution using the numpy roll function:

```
import numpy as np

b = [None, None, 4, 5] 
# or list(b) if b is a pandas Series

np.roll(b,1) == b
```

Returns:

```
> array([False,  True, False, False])
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks. For some reason it doesn't seem to work with pandas series :|

Answer (score 0):

As indicated [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing), None compares to nan who does not compare equal in Pandas/numpy.

But for the None, you can easily have a nice workaroud, using apply :

```
In[1]:
foo = pd.Series([None, 'a'])
foo==None

Out[1]:
0    False
1    False
dtype: bool 


In[2]:
foo.apply(lambda a:a==None)
Out[2]: 
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```